# Parsing error: "parseOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite, husky

I am using a vite community template ([boilerplate](https://github.com/0x219/template-vite-react)) that use husky and when I try to git commit my local repository the console throw me this:

[image]

I have all the settings done as they were on the boilerplate. The only thing I change is the "pre-commit" file in the ".husky" folder:

[image]

This is my vite.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import type { UserConfig } from "vite"; 
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import legacy from "@vitejs/plugin-legacy";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const config: UserConfig = {
    server: {
      https: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      react(),
      tsconfigPaths(),
      legacy(),
      mkcert({
        source: "coding",
      }),
    ],
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          manualChunks: {
            react: ["react"],
            "react-dom": ["react-dom"],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return config;
});
```

Comment: Could you add your `vite.config.ts`?

Comment: Done, it's already added